# LINQ Create new Xdocument by looping through existing XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, ssis, biml

I'm very new to LINQ so please bear with me :)

I'm currently trying to reverse engineer a SSIS package (.dtsx) which is in XML format into a .BIML file which is also XML based. However they have different constructs for the same objects.

So what i'm trying to do is to loop through the XML of the .dtsx package and have a basically check the type of the element and create an equivalent element in a new file but with a different name/attributes, however i will need to keep the hierarchical relationship of the objects as i create the elements in the new file.

But i'm really struggling with how i can add new elements to the new file whilst i'm looping through the source file.

Is anyone able to offer some pointers?

I'm able to loop through the file at the moment (i'm just outputting to a console window at teh moment to check understand if i'm looping corectly) but i'm struggling to add the elements into the new file

any help very much appreciated

```
    string file  = @"F:\\sample.dtsx"
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
    XNamespace env = "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";

    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xDoc.Root.Descendants(); //

    XDocument BIMLXdoc = new XDocument(
                        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
                        new XElement("Root"));
                        //BIMLXdoc.Add(new XElement("test"));  ####This doesn't work

    foreach (XElement element in elements)
            {
             // Test element and if of the correct type add new elemnt to biml file 

             IEnumerable<XAttribute> attribs = element.Attributes();

                   foreach (XAttribute attrib in attribs)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(element.Name.LocalName  + " - Attribute(" + attrib.Name.LocalName + ") - Value:(" + attrib.Value + ")");
                        }
             }          
     BIMLXdoc.Save("F:\\BIMLTest.xml");
```

Comment: Could you post your sample file so that I can test my code?

Answer (score 0):

In commented line you are trying to add node to the top level. Correct XML document has [only one root element](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp). So, add your nodes to `Root` element:

```
    var BIMLXdoc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
            new XElement("Root"));
    BIMLXdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("test"));  // This works
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new Element to your Xdoc, you need to add it in a specific place:

Change:

```
BIMLXdoc.Add(new XElement("test"));
```

To:

```
BIMLXdoc.Element("Root").Add(new XElement("TestChild", "TestChildValue"));
```

And you will have a child element.